# pyspark hbase mapreduce delete data

Tags: python, pyspark

delete the hbase data through pyspark mapreduce

- I have a hive table: row_key_table (rowkey string).
- I want to use pyspark to read the data rowkeys in the row_key_table,
- and then delete the hbase data through mapreduce. According to the rowkeys, how should I write this code?